# Google apps trigger stopped firing for some users

Tags: google-apps-script

Time based triggers for my Google script app are not working for some users.

Trigger should be fired once per day, around 1am:

```
var triggerFunction = "processRecurrentLists";  //trigger callback function name

//---------------------------------------------
function createTriggers(tmz) {
  // Trigger running at 1am depending on timezone specified in settings
  // If no timezone specified, script timezone is used (GMT)
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(triggerFunction)
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
      .inTimezone(tmz)
      .atHour(1)
      .create();
}
```

What I tried so far:

1. checked permissions - It is not related to permissions - user is able to run script manually without any errors
2. re-applied permissions - removed and granted again
3. reinstalled trigger

It is interesting that issue started appearing this October, while last update to code was made in April and it only started appearing at small, but growing, number of users.

Any ideas how to fix or at least test this?

**Update 1**
Issue is impacting others too. Some are reporting it is related to V8 engine and going back to Rhino will solve the issue, but that did not work for me.
There is an issue open for this at Google https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175139769

Comment: Did you get any error messages? Have the triggers stopped working at all or only sometimes?

Comment: in this example, you are adding a trigger through code, but did you try adding it through the trigger edit menu?

Comment: What do you mean by "Trigger running at 1am depending on timezone specified in settings"? Is trigger failing when no timezone is set? What are the timezones used when it fails?

Comment: How are you passing a parameter to createTrigger(tmz) function. Does each different person have an intermediate function?

Comment: @Kessy No, no error messages. And yes, once trigger stopped working it never fired again. But it is user specific - for most of users it still works, but rising count of those who report the issue - for them the trigger stopped firing completely. And I'm positive - trigger is still in place and active.

Comment: @Baby_Boy, no did not try adding through menu - it is script installed via Chrome Store so not really possible to instruct specific users. And pity is that it "works for me" :-(

Comment: @Rubén Good point - just checked. There is a default time zone specified, so the time zone is always specified. Plus, the issue started to appear with users for which it worked for several years in row... Going to check if it is time zone specific.

Comment: @Cooper Time zone is passed from function used for script installation. Time zone is one of user properties. If no time zone is specified, GMT is used.

Comment: And what about uninstalling and re-installing the script? Have you gotten any feedback from the users that they might have done something to disable the trigger?

Comment: @Kessy yes, reinstalling was one of the first attempts to remedy the situation, but did not help...

Comment: As the same started to appear on on one of my test accounts I was able to debug it to some extent. And it seems to be related to Google policy requiring script verification before publishing. As this script has been published since 2015 it never occured to me I need to re-verify it. Going to do that and we'll see.

Comment: Did this manage to solve the issue?

Comment: @Kessy still waiting for approval...

Comment: If you are a Google Workspace administrator you can contact with [Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) so they can take a look at your personal issue. If not, have you got any updates on the issue?

Comment: @Kessy It's not really personal issue - it is not working for normal Google accounts too. And verification did not help... :-(

Comment: It seems to work correctly if user gets "Viewer" rights to the script. I have reproduced the issue with one of my accounts. But that does not really solves the problem - there are some 8000 users using this script.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is related to V8 engine. I switched my app to V8 in April 2020 and this issue appeared in Sep-Oct 2020.

I've been finally able to fully reproduce it today.

1. create Google Apps Script project
2. copy files Code.gs and index.html attached below to your project
3. make sure to disable V8 engine in "Run" menu
4. deploy it as a web app
5. using another account navigate to published url
6. authorize the app
7. click button "Run" (Javascript console in your browser should show message "App trigger installed"
8. open script executions https://script.google.com/home/executions and remove filter
9. in approx one minute entry for TriggerTest of type "TimeDriven" should appear with status "Completed"
10. enable V8 engine in your Editor and deploy **new version** of app
11. in one minute entry for Trigger test of type "Trigger" with status "Failed" should appear in script executions...

Link to Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175139769

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setTitle('Trigger Test')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function myFunction() {
 
  // if no trigger installed
  if (ScriptApp
      .getProjectTriggers()
      .filter(function(t){return t.getHandlerFunction() === "myFunction"})
      .length == 0
      ){
        // create trigger firing every 5min
         ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
         .timeBased()
         .everyMinutes(1)
         .create();      
      }
  
  console.log("Hello from triggered function");
  return ("Hello from server");
  
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Trigger test</h1>
   <p> Click to run app <button type="button" onclick="runApp()">Run</button></p>
  </body>
  <script>
  function runApp() {
    console.log("Trying to run app...");
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(ret){console.log("App trigger installed.",ret)})
      .withFailureHandler(function(){console.log("Error running app")})
      .myFunction();
  }
  </script>
</html>
```